# Error in select statement, with union all in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In Oracle 11g, I came across an error for a query and cannot figure why it is erroring on me. Here is the query:

```
select
  main_data.issue_number,
  main_data.transaction_number
 from
 (
    select
      p1.payment_date,
      p1.media_number,
      p1.payment_amount,
      p1.issue_number, 
      p1.advice_na_number,
      name.name_address_line_1,
      name.name_address_line_2,
      name.name_address_line_3,
      name.name_address_line_4,
      name.name_address_line_5,
      name.name_address_line_6,
      name.name_address_line_7,
      name.name_address_city, 
      name.state_code,
      name.address_country_code, 
      name.zip_code, 
      name.tax_id_number,
      p1.output_tx_number_prin,
      p1.output_tx_number_int,
      '' as "transaction_number",
      p1header.check_account_number

    from 
    p1
    left join name on p1.name_address_number = name.name_address_number
    left join p1header on p1.issue_number = p1header.issue_number

  UNION ALL

  select 
      check.date_of_payment,
      check.media_number, 
      check.payment_amount,
      check.issue_number,
      check.payee_na_number,
      name.name_address_line_1,
      name.name_address_line_2,
      name.name_address_line_3,
      name.name_address_line_4,
      name.name_address_line_5,
      name.name_address_line_6,
      name.name_address_line_7,
      name.name_address_city, 
      name.state_code,
      name.address_country_code, 
      name.zip_code, 
      name.tax_id_number,
      '' as "output_tx_number_prin",
      '' as "output_tx_number_int",
      check.transaction_number,
      check.dda_number as "check_account_number"
  from check
  left join name on check.payee_na_number = name.name_address_number
) main_data
```

Selecting individual fields like above will give me an "invalid identifier error". If I do `select *` then it gives me back the data without any error. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: whenever I see this error I assume an invalid alias.  Are you totally sure that you are using the aliases of the fields and not the original column names?  Or perhaps the table main_table doesn't match what is being used in the select statement?

Comment: I did, I even took the query inside the main_data placeholder and run it without receiving the error. What is odd is that when I use select *, the data returns without any error.

Comment: is this the actual query? Or a replica?  Is it possible to provide the actual, unedited query? If you can, that might help us figure this out.

Comment: It is too long to post the comment here, but I have edited the original post to include it.

Comment: You have used `'' as "transaction_number"` in the inner query.  The double quotes make the name case sensitive.  But the outer query selects `main_data.transaction_number` without double quotes, which means it is treated as "TRANSACTION_NUMBER".  Avoid using double quotes in names.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old quoted identifier problem... see point 9 in the [database object naming documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm), and note that Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers.

You've put your column alias as lower case inside double-quotes. That means that any references to it also have to be quoted and exactly match the case. So this would work:

```
select
  main_data.issue_number,
  main_data."transaction_number"
from
...
```

But unless you have a burning need to have that alias like that - and I doubt you do as all the identifier names from the actual table columns are not quoted - it would be simpler to remove the double quotes from the inner selects:

```
select
  main_data.issue_number,
  main_data.transaction_number
 from
 (
    select
  ...
      '' as transaction_number,
      p1header.check_account_number
  ...
  UNION ALL
  select 
    ...
      '' as output_tx_number_prin,
      '' as output_tx_number_int,
      check.transaction_number,
      check.dda_number as check_account_number
    ...
```

You don't actually *need* to alias the columns in the second branch of the union; the column identifiers will all be taken from the first branch.

Comment: thank you so much. Very good information for me to keep in mind.